# Separar entre variables categoricas y numericas

Tags: python

tengo un dataset con valores categóricos y numéricos (https://www.kaggle.com/gpandi007/usa-housing-dataset) y necesitaría una forma de dividir este dataset de manera sencilla sin tener que recurrir a llamar a las columnas una a una debido a que son cerca de 75 columnas diferentes.

Esto necesito hacerlo debido a que se me pide hacer lo siguiente:

-Tabla de frecuencias de las variables categóricas
-Matriz de correlación de las numéricas

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Un solución más sencilla es utilizar el método de `Pandas`:

```
df.select_dtypes(include='object')
```

Algunos `datasets` utilizan el tipo `category` por lo que sería bueno incluirlo también:

```
df_categoricas = df.select_dtypes(include=['object','category'])
df_numericas = df.select_dtypes(include='number')
```

Enlace a la documentación oficial:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html

Edit: para mostrar la frecuencia de cada atributo categórico

```
for cat in df_categoricas.columns:
    print(f"Frecuencia {cat} : {df_categoricas[cat].value_counts(normalize=True)}")
```

En principio no hay un método directo para hacerlo

Comment: Genial! Gracias! Pero para hacer la tabla de frecuencias de las variables categoricas hay alguna forma rapida de hacerla en vez de ir una a una usando:      print("Tabla de frecuencias de '''DUAL_SIM \n", 100* train_set['dual_sim'].value_counts() / len(train_set['dual_sim']))'''

Comment: En principio creo que no hay ninguna forma rápida de hacerla. Lo único que te puedo decir es que value_counts tiene un parámetro `normalize` que si lo pones a `True`te saca directamente el porcentaje.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez has cargado los datos en un dataframe, digamos `df`, mediante `df.dtypes` puedes averiguar el tipo de cada una de las columnas.

Verás que algunas son de tipo `int64`, otras de tipo `float64`, etc. y otras muchas de tipo `object`, que es como Pandas clasifica a las que no puede interpretar como numéricas (y que generalmente deja en forma de cadenas de caracteres).

Entiendo que en tu caso las "categóricas" son precisamente las no numéricas. Así pues puedes hallar la lista de las que son numéricas y la lista de las que no son numéricas con algo como esto:

```
tipos = df.dtypes
numericas = tipos[tipos != object].index
no_numericas = tipos[tipos == object].index
```

En este caso se obtendría en `numericas` la lista:

```
       ['Id', 'MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual',
       'OverallCond', 'YearBuilt', 'YearRemodAdd', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1',
       'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF',
       'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath',
       'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd',
       'Fireplaces', 'GarageYrBlt', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF',
       'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch', '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea',
       'MiscVal', 'MoSold', 'YrSold']
```

Y en `no_numericas` la lista:

```
       ['MSZoning', 'Street', 'Alley', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities',
       'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2',
       'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st',
       'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation',
       'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2',
       'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir', 'Electrical', 'KitchenQual',
       'Functional', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual',
       'GarageCond', 'PavedDrive', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'MiscFeature',
       'SaleType', 'SaleCondition']
```